# Unable to pass parameters into Sequence Template - WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are trying to create generic parameterised sequences for reuse, using sequence templates in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. However the sequence template never receives the parameter passed from the Call Template mediator. Here's the same configuration we use for the template,

```
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test_template">
   <sequence>
      <log level="custom">
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="MESSAGE" expression="$func:message"></property>
      </log>
   </sequence>
</template>
```

...and the sequence where we call it from...

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="template_test">
   <log>
      <property name="POSITION" value="CALLING_TEMPLATE"></property>
   </log>
   <call-template target="test_template">
      <with-param name="message" value="Hello World!"></with-param>
   </call-template>
</sequence>
```

The value reported in the log file is always `null`. Can anyone point at the reason for this?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Chamila. I had to also change the parameter name in the Call template mediator to not have the $func prefix to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the argument being passed to the template as a `<parameter>`.

```
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test_template">
   <parameter name="message" />
   <sequence>
      <log level="custom">
         <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="MESSAGE" expression="$func:message"></property>
      </log>
   </sequence>
</template>
```

Imagine this as equivalent to a method signature where the input arguments are defined within brackets.